# How to set size of a component in a GridLayout and expand JTextArea while typing?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm creating a chat but that doesn't matter. I have no issues yet, all is working fine, but I want to change the UI appearance so the user can have a bigger JTextArea instead of a button occupying more space than needed. Also, I would want to resize the JTextArea rather than writing several text in only one line. Finally, I have to thank you for spending your time helping me :D

**Objectives:**

- Set size of JLabel or JTextArea so the button stays smaller.
- Expand JLabel when text is reaching the right limit and put it in a new line (kinda WhatsApp).

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class MyFirstChatSO extends JFrame {

  JLabel title;
  JTextArea messages;
  JTextField text;
  JButton send;

    public MyFirstChatSO () {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,10));

        title = new JLabel("-Chat-");
          title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          title.setFont(new Font("Gabriola",Font.ITALIC,34));
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        messages = new JTextArea();
          messages.setEnabled(false);
          messages.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(168,168,168),2,true));
        add(messages, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
          subPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
            text = new JTextField();
          subPanel.add(text);
            send = new JButton("Send");
          subPanel.add(send);
        add(subPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFirstChatSO chat = new MyFirstChatSO();
          chat.setSize(600,450);
          chat.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          chat.setVisible(true);
          chat.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

> If any other methods such as using different layoutsManagers are the solution it would be good to know about it.

Another fail, but this time with GridBagLayout (I don't know how to use it, help me pls):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class MyFirstChatSO extends JFrame {

  JLabel title;
  JTextArea messages;
  JTextField text;
  JButton send;

    public MyFirstChatSO () {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,10));

        title = new JLabel("-Chat-");
          title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          title.setFont(new Font("Gabriola",Font.ITALIC,34));
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        messages = new JTextArea();
          messages.setEnabled(false);
          messages.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(168,168,168),2,true));
        add(messages, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
      subPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();
      gb.weightx = 1;
      gb.weighty = 1;
      gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        text = new JTextField();
        gb.gridx = 0;
        gb.gridy = 0;
        gb.gridwidth = 6;
        gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      subPanel.add(text,gb);
        send = new JButton("Send");
        gb.gridx = 7;
        gb.gridy = 0;
      subPanel.add(send,gb);
    add(subPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFirstChatSO chat = new MyFirstChatSO();
          chat.setSize(600,450);
          chat.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          chat.setVisible(true);
          chat.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Set size of JLabel or JTextArea so the button stays smaller."* I would either consider using a `GridBagLayout` or a combination of compounding layout

Comment: *"Expand JLabel when text is reaching the right limit and put it in a new line (kinda WhatsApp)."* - Could of thoughts.  Maybe consider using a readonly `JTextArea` NOT embedded in it's own `JScrollPane`.  Funny enough, `GridBagLayout` will allow it to grow as needed.  You could also use a `JLabel` and wrap the text in `html`

Comment: Oh, thanks... but, ¿Could you post it as an official answer, please?

Comment: Also, I tried it with that gridbaglayout here my attempt (still doesn't work): https://code.sololearn.com/c0TfyKCNq9Th/#java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another fail, but this time with GridBagLayout (I don't know how to use it, help me pls):

Yes, you need to understand how it works.  Always have [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and the JavaDocs available ;)

So, I started with...

```
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

text = new JTextArea(1, 80);
text.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY), new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));
subPanel.add(text, gbc);

gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
gbc.weightx = 0;
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
send = new JButton("Send");
subPanel.add(send, gbc);
```

And I ended up with something like...

[image: GridBagLayout]

But wait a second, this example is using a `JTextArea`?!  Why!?

Ah, that's because I'm a sneaky, cheaty pants ;)

[image: Auto expanding magic]

By using a `JTextArea` this way, you get an auto expanding text field, for free.  Now, it's important to remember, that this is unconstrained, meaning that the user could keeping pressing enter and making the `JTextArea` fill up more and more space.

To fix that becomes complicated and I'd look into the `Scrollable` `interface` for some ideas